# RKMappingTest has no methods (RestKit)

Tags: ios, unit-testing, restkit

I'm working with `RestKit` and trying to do unit tests per the Unit Testing Guide on their Github wiki.

When I try to create an instance of `RKMappingTest`, its like it only has the `NSObject` methods on it. it doesn't have the `testWithMapping:` method or any others that come up in the autocomplete and if I type it myself there is an error. Also, `respondsToSelector:` returns `NO` for the `testWithMapping` method.

So, since the class is available I'm sure the header is there but I can't figure out why the methods are not there. The `textFixture` stuff works fine as well. I've restarted XCode but can't seem to find out what is going on here. Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the Wiki page. There was an error with the message call it should be:

```
+ testForMapping:sourceObject:destinationObject:
```

instead of

```
+ testForMapping:withSourceObject:destinationObject:
```